# Google SEO - remove site map from search result

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I am an amateur to SEO. I have a new site recently and submitted the site map to GWT. But after several weeks. I found when I search my domain in google. The site map  also appears to be one of the links in the search result.

How could I prevent if from showing up in the search result?

Comment: Who cares? There's nothing in the sitemap that anybody shouldn't see. Why do you want to do this? The result with the accepted answer from @BluesRockAddict is that Google can't even access it(which makes no sense if you submitted it to them), not just that it doesn't show in results.

Comment: @Su, Can you suggest a better way to accomplish what OP is asking about though?

Comment: @Su' I also have some of the concern that the approach BluesRockAddict provided will result in that way. I haven't fully thought it over, so I haven't done anything yet. It is not so important, because it will mostly never show up front in any organic search. But I just think it look quite odd that the site map is contained in the result sometime.

Comment: I can't suggest anything better, because I don't think it should be done at all unless more information is provided that defines an actual problem. This is a public file, and it's *correct* that it shows up in search, assuming it works for the terms submitted.

Comment: How about scenario where wrong sitemap file was submitted to google via GWT by mistake? Web-site owner realizes his mistake but he doesn't have the old sitemap file anymore (and might not know how to create one) and the new sitemap already indexed by google and "wrong" links are showing up in search results? Not so hard to imagine this happening in real life, is it?

Comment: Actually, I *am* having a hard time imagining that scenario. Feel free to open a question if it ever actually happens. But anyway: [Delete the old sitemap](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34598) from GWT (I don't see why it matters that you don't have the old one.) and submit the new one. (Your question implies they didn't?) Bad URLs will fall off on their own as they should be 404(right?), and if it's really urgent, [submit removal requests](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164734).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Stop Google indexing sitemap using HTACCESS**

In my honest opinion the best method stopping Google indexing sitemaps  by using the htaccess since technically robots.txt is a denying access while noinded is readable yet won't index.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <Files sitemap.xml>
       Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use no follow on sitemap or go to google webmaster tool click on Site configuration after that click on  Sitemaps and after that Select the url and Delete Selected.

Answer (score -2):

Two things:

1. You should delete sitemap from your account using Webmaster Tools (Site configuration -> Sitemaps -> Select -> Delete Selected)
2. You should change your [robots.txt](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) to prevent Google from accessing the sitemap file (i.e. some like Disallow: /sitemap.xml)

Comment: Thanks, I need to done both two or either of them?

Comment: If you want sitemap to eventually disappear from google's search results, you'd need to make changes to your robots.txt file. That would not prevent "bad" guys from indexing your sitemap though as their bots ignore the robots.txt anyway. If you're concerned about it, you should remove the actual sitemap.xml file from your server. Deleting it from GWT is optional (and mainly cosmetic).

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, care to explain?

Comment: The suggestion oversteps the question. If the sitemap was personally submitted, we can assume Google should have access to it; asker just wants it not in results(though I see nothing wrong with that). Blocking that access runs counter to the entire point of having a sitemap file.

Comment: So, how would you accomplish removing the sitemap from google's search results without preventing google from accessing that file?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible, to be honest. But as I said, I don't think there's any point, either.

Comment: How then suggested answer "oversteps the question"? Blocking google from indexing sitemap file will cause it *eventually* to disappear from google's index, so the answer is actually accurate to the question asked.

Comment: disallowing the sitemp in robots.txt prevents google from crawling or downloading the sitemap.  It wouldn't actually prevent Googlef from indexing the sitemap since Google already knows the contents.  Bybe's answer is correct.  You should use the X-Robots-Tag header to noindex the sitemap.